# How to access variable from main, java

Tags: java, jvm

I am having trouble trying to make a HashMap accessible  to other methods in the class that it's in.

Here is basically what I am trying to do,

```
class object
    method main
        this.test=9
    method fire
        output this.test
```

Here is the real code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class problem {
    public HashMap dict;

    public problem() {
        HashMap<String, String[]> dict = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

        // put everything into hashmap
        String[] items = { "toys", "sun" };
        dict.put("animal", items);
        String[] items_2 = { "fun", "games" };
        view.put("human", items_2);

        this.view = view;

        // start
        this.BeginM();
    }

    public void BeginM() {
        System.out.println(this.view.get("human")[0]); // should give "fun"
    }
}
```

I get this error at the output stage:

```
array required, but java.lang.Object found
```

Comment: Interesting coincidence - you left out the line of code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Chuck, he didn't leave anything out. However, it's correct that the above won't compile.

Comment: I'm loving the stream of edits that somehow make this question less readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know what?  I've had one of those days where no matter how hard you try nothing quite ends up working right so, in order to have *something* actually working right, I'm going to fix up your code!

I sometimes see people post total rewrites of strange questions here and I've always wondered *why!?*  Now I know, it's to compensate for having a day where one of your virtual machines goes belly up for no reason, you've got a bug that eludes reproduction until the moment you look away and your dog forgot his housetraining spontaneously.

Anyway, you need to figure out whether you want that variable to be called `dict` or `view`.  Pick one, but you'll need to stick with it.  I don't really care, but I'm using `dict` here.  If you prefer the other, hey, it's your code, do what you like!  But don't use both, that'll get confusing.

Your problem is that in your field, you're just using `HashMap`.  Use the fancy well-typed stuff, or cast.  Otherwise, `HashMap` just holds `Object`s.  And an `Object` isn't a `String[]`.  So you either need to cast the results of `get()` to a `String[]`, or you can just forget about all that and use the fancy well-typed stuff (sometimes we call that "generics").  I'm going to use the fancy well-typed stuff (`HashMap<String, String[]>`), but like I said - it's your code, cast if you want to!

Anyway, that gets us to:

```
public class problem
{
    HashMap<String, String[]> dict;

    public problem()
    {
        HashMap<String, String[]> dict = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

        // put everything into hashmap
        String[] items =
        {
            "toys", "sun"
        };
        dict.put("animal", items);
        String[] items_2 =
        {
            "fun", "games"
        };
        dict.put("human", items_2);

        this.dict = dict;

        // start
        this.BeginM();
    }

    public void BeginM()
    {
        System.out.println(this.dict.get("human")[0]); // should give "fun"
    }
}
```

See my line 3?  By declaring that field `dict` as a `HashMap<String, String[]>`, now `BeginM()` knows what kind of objects it holds and you won't get that error any more.

Although I'd take it a step further and make it a bit more concise and a bit less error prone:

```
public class Problem
{
    private final HashMap<String, String[]> dict;

    public void Problem()
    {
        dict = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

        dict.put("animal", new String[] { "toys, "sun" });
        dict.put("human", new String[] { "fun", "games" });

        BeginM();
    }

    public void BeginM()
    {
        System.out.println(dict.get("human")[0]);
    }
}
```

So what did I do there?  Well, first I capitalized `Problem`.  It's sort of convention to have class names that start with a capital letter.  Not mandatory, of course, but it's nice to have, especially when you're working with other developers.  Case in point: I thought your constructor for `problem` was a method that lacked a return value!  Also, I made `dict` final and private, this is so that you don't accidentally overwrite that field later.  And I made it private, which is good design.  If somebody else needs to get at it, we can give them an accessor method.  Finally, I got rid of `this.`, because I don't really like it - but, hey, still your code, put it back if you want!

Comment: +1 since you had a hard day, and this is a decent answer to a poorly formed question.

Comment: wow, awesome, i'm happy that i got an well explained answer, thanks!

Comment: @PaulWagland: thanks!  My initial comment was so remarkably unhelpful that I decided I should probably repent and write a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `this.view.get("human")` returns a String, not an array. You need to use `this.view.get("human").charAt(0)` instead of `this.view.get("human")[0]`, since Java Strings can't be indexed like arrays.

Comment: I don't think `this.view.get("human")` could return anything, since `this.view` isn't defined anywhere.  But I think the intention (although, I admit, it's hard to tell) is to have a `HashMap<String, String[]>`, which would mean that yes, `view.get("human")` would return an array.

Comment: `view` is implied to be a HashMap because of the way he accesses it. `get()` is defined in the Map class.

Comment: I don't think the compiler will spontaneously create a variable because of an implication.  And if it does, then I need to start using that one.

Comment: I wasn't saying that his code would compile. I was just saying that we can deduce the variable datatype. I was focusing more on describing the syntax error and not his messy structure.

Comment: I see.  I agree that we can deduce it and I suggest that the author intends `HashMap<String, String[]>`, which would make `get("human")[0]` perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Change: (BTW, missing from your example)

```
Map view = new HashMap<String,String[])
```

to;

```
Map<String,String[]> view = new HashMap<String,String[])
```

Comment: Yes and I know it does not compile and I know that particular error is cause by missing generics on the var of type Map.  This kid is simply trying to learn Java and he needs to be guided a little.

Comment: Missing the types on the Map will just bring up some warnings in the code, not errors. His problem is about the name of the variables, and the `main` function, which he hasn't posted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Not corret. For his usage, map.get("x")[0], the missing generics cause a compile error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object".  Try it.

Comment: You can do something like `String[] data = (String[])map.get("x"); System.out.println(data[0]);` and not use the `Map<String, String[]>` declaration. The main problem here is that he needs guidance on programming basics, because this error can pop up on C++, .Net or any other language.

Comment: @ChuckFricano is obviously correct here.  The non-generic `HashMap` is equivalent to `HashMap<Object, Object>` and thus would require a cast.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - My solution is correct.  There are likely others.  In this case, the missing generics cause an error, not a warning and properly using generics correct the problem.  Casting is unsafe.  That is why generics were added to Java.